# Close a tab with js that my script didn't open

Tags: node.js, tabs

I am working on an application that uses a https, express, nodeJS webserver to serve a webpage to the user. When the user hits "start.bat" the node server launches and a browser is opened to localhost. Currently, the user has to CTRL + W the browser and CTRL + C the server to shut off the application. I want to implement a system that, when ESC is pressed, shuts down the server and exits the current tab. Currently, I have a system that redirects the user to localhost/shutdown when ESC is pressed. NodeJS has a /shutdown endpoint that serves the user public/shutdown.html and then, after 2 second, exits the process.

```
app.get(
  "/shutdown",
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir + "/public/shutdown.html"));
    next();
  },
  () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      process.exit();
    }, 2000);
  }
);
```

Now, all I need to do is close the localhost/shutdown tab once the server has properly shutdown. After some quick searching I found the window.close() function - a function of which, due to a security patch, was no longer able to close just any tab. Sure enough, I got the `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them` error, thus ending my short burst of hope that I had found an easy way out of my dilema. I have attempted to have nodeJS open a new index.html which would then open the popup tab of the game. This would enable me permission to exit out the popup tab with (newtab).close() as it was my script that opened it. I realized that, even if I was able to close this new tab, I would always have one original tab opened because my script hadn't opened it. If anybody has an idea as to a workaround to this problem I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is not possible due to security limitations, you better take a look on different approaches.

Comment: you could try using socket.io for your express server and user interface, you could fire off a kill command from socket.io to the browser page (this assumes that you control the browser code), you would trigger it to run RIGHT before the server is killed